# How can I show to googleMap in custom dialog? (doesn't show google map)

Tags: android, kotlin, customdialog

I have created a custom dialog and initialized a map, but it isn't shown in the dialog view.

I think logcat message is a hint, but I can't catch it. The message:

> E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null

This is `DialogFragment` code:

```
class ScannerMapDialog : DialogFragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_scanner,container,false)
        (childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.scanner_map) as? SupportMapFragment)?.getMapAsync(this)
        val btn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt_done)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }

        return view
    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val width = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.85).toInt()
        val height = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.40).toInt()
        dialog!!.window?.setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap
        googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker)).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        val baseLocate = LatLng(37.507543, 127.053699)
        markerOptions.position(baseLocate)
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(baseLocate, 16f))
    }
}
```